# Child div height in absolute position parent

Tags: html, css, position, height, absolute

Please assist me to resolve this strange issue.

```
<div style="position: absolute;width:700px;height:410px;background-color: #e2e2e2;border: solid black 1px; left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;margin: auto;">
    <div style="padding: 0px 20px;">
        Header
    </div>
    <div style="border: solid black 2px;height: 30px;padding: 10px;overflow-y: auto;">
        Content
    </div>
 </div>
```

The height property of the content div was set to 30px, but when rendering the page it shows physically as 6px. I noticed that it sums up the border and padding with the height; so the calculation will be

2px + 2px (top and bottom borders)
10px + 10px (top and bottom padding)
6px (physical height)

Total: 30px

I think that making absolute position of the parent div has an effect, but didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: is there any `box-sizing` property applied to it, If yes, then you need t remove that for your requirement. if Not, Then you need to share little more of your work.

Comment: Can't reproduce here. I don't see a difference between your source with or without the position:absolute removed. Can you post a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Thank you all for your support. Thanks Aman, I changed the box-sizing property. It was set by default in the browser as box-sizing: border-box then I changed it to box-sizing: content-box.